# how to use local system as a file manager in webhosting

Tags: web-hosting

I have my project in my local system, I don't want to use custom file managers provided by hosting sites but i want to make use of my local system as file manager is it possible?  if yes please explain me the process.

Answer (score 0):

We could not able to use our local system as a file manager, But you can use FTP/SFTP  tools as follows to upload and download the files.

*Winscp
*Filezilla

In order to copy the files from the local machine to the server end.